# domPDF - Table always going to bottom if reaching page height

Tags: php, html, css, dompdf

I'm using DOMPDF to generating PDF files but I have a little problem.
Here is my basic table for this template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>PDF</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h4>List 1:</h4>
                    <ol>
                        @foreach ($listArray_1 as $inv)
                            <li>{{ $inv->firstname }} {{ $inv->middlename }} {{ $inv->lastname }}</li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ol>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <h4>List 2:</h4>
                    <ol>
                        @foreach ($listArray_2 as $inv)
                            <li>{{ $inv->firstname }} {{ $inv->middlename }} {{ $inv->lastname }}</li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ol>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <h4>List 3:</h4>
                    <ol>
                        @foreach ($listArray_3 as $inv)
                            <li>{{ $inv->firstname }} {{ $inv->middlename }} {{ $inv->lastname }}</li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ol>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <h4>List 4:</h4>
                    <ol>
                        @foreach ($listArray_4 as $inv)
                            <li>{{ $inv->firstname }} {{ $inv->middlename }} {{ $inv->lastname }}</li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ol>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

But if some `<td>` is larger than page height, it's making 2 firsts pages blank and on third page rendering cutted content (cutted to end of page).
Where is problem? In CSS or DOM PDF? (I cannot use wkhtmltopdf :/ )

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution using another library: 
I use mPDF for this task. I can imagine it is a very hard process internally in mPDF, but managed to get a good pdf, using multiple tables that might or might not span multiple pages. All goes well.

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['tempDir' => __DIR__ . '/tmp']);
$mpdf->shrink_tables_to_fit = false;
$mpdf->WriteHTML( <<<HTML
<style>    
table
{
     page-break-inside: avoid;
}
</style>
<table>.... LONG table</table>
<table>.... another table</table>
<table>.... LONG table</table>
HTML
);
```

`